# PhantomJSDriver "cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:xxxx/"

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

So I have a console app that is running Selenium.PhantomJS and it works fine on my localhost, but when I put it into production, I get the following:

[image: Output]

Looking at the logfile, I see

"Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:4545/"

I thought it might be a firewall thing, but I ended up turning the firewall off completely to test and still got this result.

Comment: Did you import a web driver?

Comment: Yes, there is a WebDriver.dll

Comment: Make sure anything else is not using this port! Apart from that should work.

Comment: It loads up on a random port, I've checked and we're only using 3 ports on that server, none of which it has started up as.

Comment: My advice then would be to use last version of PhantomJS, if it's not. Also, double check if something is monitoring traffic, some third party apps. Try also launch a ghost driver separately and see if it works!